# Taylor series approximation of Error function on complex domain

Tags: series-expansion

I am using Taylor series to approximate error function on complex domain.

For a given $z\in D\subset \mathbb{C}^1$, we know the Taylor series of error function (around point $z_0=0$) is uniformly convergent to $\mathrm{erf}(z)$ itself on whole $D$, i.e.,

\begin{equation}
\mathrm{erf}(z)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)n!}z^{2n+1}
\end{equation}

However, I found it very weird when I tried to implement it in Mathematica.
Here is my code:

```
NN = 150;
z = 5 + 5 I;
For[k = 0; sum = 0, k < NN, k++, 
  term = (-1)^k/(2 k + 1) N[(z^(2 k + 1)/k!)];
  sum = sum + term];
erfapp = N[sum*2/Sqrt[Pi]];
erfref = N[Erf[z]];
errorr = erfapp - erfref;
Print["error=", Abs[errorr], "  z=", z]
```

The error between the true value and Taylor approximation is 10356.9, and it can not be reduced further by increasing the truncation number, which is the strange part.

Any suggestions or comments will be appreciated! ^_^

Comment: You are using `MachinePrecision` which neither tracks nor controls precision. Change **all** uses of `N` to include a specified precision, e.g., `N[Erf[z], 30]`, this will result in use of arbitrary-precision.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Dear Col. Hanlon, thank you so much for your comment! I changed all uses ```N``` to include a specified precision 100, and it works for the $z$ with integer real and imaginary parts. But I still got problem for non-integer case, e.g., $z=0+6.1i$, the series still can not approximate...

Comment: If you introduce a machine precision number (e.g. `0 + 6.1 *I`), any calculations with that number will be done at machine precision. Use either `z  =  0 + 6.1\`100 *I;` or `z = SetPrecision[0 + 6.1*I, 100];`

Comment: You could also use `z = 0 + 6.1*I // Rationalize;`

Comment: @Bob Hanlon: Thank you soooooo much! I really need to study more about the precision...